# prepare SQLite insert statement inside php for loop

Tags: php, for-loop, mysqli-multi-query

I want to prepare an SQL insert statement inside PHP for loop, my statement is something like this

```
$insert_stmt = "";
for($x=1; $x<=$all_property[duration]; $x++) {
    $insert_stmt .= "INSERT INTO `schedule` VALUES ($all_property[serial], $_POST[Day$x])";

echo $insert_stmt;
mysqli_free_result($insert_stmt);   // Free result set for next query
}
```

wherein I expect the result to be like

```
INSERT INTO `schedule` VALUES ($all_property[serial], $_POST[Day1] //for first loop
INSERT INTO `schedule` VALUES ($all_property[serial], $_POST[Day2] //for second loop
```

And so on, but I am getting error

> syntax error, unexpected '$x' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ']' in
>   schedule.php on line 163

so, if any one can help me rectify what is wrong in my query.

Answer (score 1):

Updated:

As the fields are not constant and also they are string, you need to quote them, so just use this line:

```
$insert_stmt = "INSERT INTO schedule VALUES (‘".$all_property[serial]."’, ‘".$_POST["Day".$x]."’)";
```